# Cover whole height of a button with img

Tags: css, sass

I have the following html code and css styling for a button. In the button I want to show a picture on the right which should always cover the whole height of the button. It doesn't matter if some content of the picture isn't showing but it should always cover the right side of the button no matter how small the screen is. Right now at some point the picture won't cover the whole height. Do you have any suggestions how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0, 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dishName {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
}

.dishDescription {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dishPrice {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.restaurantMenuImg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 65%;
}

.restaurantMenuImg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>
      <div class=dishName>
        <text>dish name</text>
      </div>
      <div class=dishDescription>
        <text>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</text>
      </div>
      <div class=dishPrice>
        <text>900€</text>
      </div>
      <div class=restaurantMenuImg>
        <img src=https://images.pexels.com/photos/1581384/pexels-photo-1581384.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500/>
      </div>
    </button>
```

Comment: I assume you are just wanting a background image for the button? What you have now is not good! Maybe include a screenshot of what you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like in my snippet below: I added flex settings to the button (`display:flex; flex-direction:column; flex-wrap:wrap`) and replaced `min-height: 200px;` and `max-height: 200px;` with `height: 200px;` to have a *defined* height (for the next setting to work). Also, I added `height: 100%;` to the `.restaurantMenuImg` container of the image to make it full height, and the image inside it as well.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0, 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dishName {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
}

.dishDescription {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dishPrice {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.restaurantMenuImg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 65%;
  height: 100%;
}

.restaurantMenuImg img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>
      <div class=dishName>
        <text>dish name</text>
      </div>
      <div class=dishDescription>
        <text>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</text>
      </div>
      <div class=dishPrice>
        <text>900€</text>
      </div>
      <div class=restaurantMenuImg>
        <img src=https://images.pexels.com/photos/1581384/pexels-photo-1581384.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500/>
      </div>
    </button>
```

Solution with a landscape-proportion image:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0, 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dishName {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
}

.dishDescription {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dishPrice {
  padding-left: 2%;
  top: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.restaurantMenuImg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 65%;
  height: 100%;
}

.restaurantMenuImg img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>
      <div class=dishName>
        <text>dish name</text>
      </div>
      <div class=dishDescription>
        <text>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</text>
      </div>
      <div class=dishPrice>
        <text>900€</text>
      </div>
      <div class=restaurantMenuImg>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"/>
      </div>
    </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works for fine for this image but if the image has landscape format, at a certain height the image won't be covering the whole height. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Well, then just make the image `height: 100%; width: auto` (I just added an example. Naturally, a lot of it is cut off, which can't be avoided taking in account the space there is for it)

Comment: okay thank you so much. I think this will work!